# Mixing in module with attr_accessible, has_one, has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, multiple-inheritance, mixins

Can I do somehting like this in Rails ?

```
module Authored
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible creation_date
end

class Line < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Authored
end

class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Authored
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :creations, :class_name => 'Authored'
end
```

Or do I need to use simple inheritance, even if my Authored classes have different class hierarchies ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
module Authored
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    belongs_to :user
    attr_accessible :creation_date
  end
end

class Line < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Authored
end

class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Authored
end
```

For more info on `ActiveSupport::Concern`, http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks :) Seems like it won't work out for the has_many in my User. I probably need to deal with it using a polymorphic association.